# Making AJAX requests when a Map is changed by the user with the Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm building a website with ASP.NET MVC where one feature displays some points on a Google map, using the Google Maps Javascript API. As I have a lot of points, I don't want to fetch them all; rather, I want to get only the ones that are in the current view area that the user is looking at on the map (the bounding box).

To do that, I will make an AJAX request to my C# code that returns all the points inside a certain bounding box. However, I need to somehow create an event handler that catches whenever the map is panned or zoomed by the user.

**How can I detect when a map using the Google Maps Javascript API is panned or zoomed and fire an event handler?**

**UPDATE:** I know that I have to implement an event listener. Can someone point me towards a list of events that I can use for the Map object? `click` is one of those events, but what are the ones that relate to zooming and panning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the `idle` event:

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Events</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();

      console.log('North East: ' +
                  bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + ' ' + 
                  bounds.getNorthEast().lng());

      console.log('South West: ' +
                  bounds.getSouthWest().lat() + ' ' + 
                  bounds.getSouthWest().lng());

      // Your AJAX code in here ...
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition, you can find the list of all events exported by the `google.maps.Map` object from the API Reference:

- [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference: Map Class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was looking for such a reference page but didn't find the part you pointed me to.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need use an listener...
in this case an event listener..

[gmaps events reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html)

if you use v3 search on v3 reference for listeners

Comment: Can you point me towards a list of events that I can use for the Map object? "click" is one of them, but what are the ones that relate to zooming and panning?

Comment: i post a new answer cause i can't edit my first, i have no idea why
check out the link, i think this is what you looking for
i hope give you some help

Answer (score 0):

this is a list of Gevents-> [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/gevent.htm)

probably are not listed all